# Android advanced scrollable View like MapView

Tags: android

View that is scrollable similar to this picture:

http://s13.postimage.org/7eqznyzo7/advancedscroll.png

Is there any view in Android that can scroll like MapView? I need to add an ImageView in that view.

I have tried [this](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/), but it did not work. I tried to add a ScrollView+Horizontal, but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Please explain "did not work" part.  I used that same page as a reference and successfully implemented it.  Post your code and show where the issues are.

Comment: only horizontally moving the View